CSS: target p only in parent divs with columns?
I have an Elementor/Wordpress site with some articles in columns. I need to target only paragraphs in text with columns.
In Elementor the P is child to a div that is child to a div with the column settings (2 deep). I've tried playing with :has() but I cannot figure out the syntax to make it work.

I tried a few things like:
div:has([style*="column-count"]) p {
color: red;
}


.elementor-element .elementor-widget-container p {
color: #F00;
} should do the trick.

Where is style="column-count: something" in the HTML?

You can't use an attribute selector for styles inherited by CSS, if that's what you're intending. Attribute selectors only match inline attributes.
